# PowerShell New-Object and HTML Output Issue

Tags: html, powershell

I am trying to create statistics for a server using PowerShell. and also learning PowerShell.

This is the code I have

```
Function Get-PingHost
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param([string]$Hostname = "ServerName")

    "The HostName is " + $Hostname
    $status=get-wmiobject win32_pingstatus -Filter "Address='$Hostname'" | Select-Object statuscode
    "The Status Code is " + $status.statuscode
    if($status.statuscode -eq 0)
    {
        $HostNameStatusInfo = $Hostname + " is REACHABLE"
    }
    else
    {
       $HostNameStatusInfo = $Hostname + " is NOT REACHABLE"
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $HostNameStatusInfo
**<COMMENT>** If I remove the above New-Object code is still get an incorrect output as mentioned below in the **HTML OutPut**
  }

$fragments = @()
$fragments+=$top

$fragments+="<a href='javascript:toggleAll();' title='Click to toggle all sections'>Expand All/Collapse All</a>"

$Text = "SQL Server Ping Status"
$div = $Text.Replace(" ","_")
$fragments+= "<a href='javascript:toggleDiv(""$div"");' title='click to collapse or expand this section'><h2>$Text</h2></a><div id=""$div"">"
$fragments+= Get-PingHost -Hostname $Hostname | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -As List
$fragments+="</div>"
$fragments+= $html.InnerXml
$fragments+="</div>"
$fragments+= "<p class='footer'>$(get-date)</p>"
```

The Output I get in **HTML** is:
SQL Server Ping Status
*:  31
*:  20

**Error Message**
ew-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'Property'. Cannot convert the "ServerName is REACHABLE" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
At line:38 char:45
+     New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $HostNameStatusInfo
+                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: So basically you do not need that object .

Answer (score 0):

Apologies... The issue has been resolved...
The code is as below: -

```
#GET OPERATING SYSTEM INFORMATION
Function Get-PingHost
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param([string]$Hostname = "ServerName")

    $status=get-wmiobject win32_pingstatus -Filter "Address='$Hostname'" | Select-Object statuscode
    #"The Status Code is " + $status.statuscode
    if($status.statuscode -eq 0)
    {
        $Hostname + " is <b>REACHABLE</b>"

    }
    else
    {
       $Hostname + " is <b>NOT REACHABLE</b>"
       #Basically You Don't Need to assign this to the String Variable and 
       #then display the string variable...
    }
}

#endregion

$fragments = @()
$top = ""

$fragments+=$top

$fragments+="<a href='javascript:toggleAll();' title='Click to toggle all sections'>Expand All/Collapse All</a>"
$Text = "SQL Server Ping Status"
$div = $Text.Replace(" ","_")
$fragments+= "<a href='javascript:toggleDiv(""$div"");' title='click to collapse or expand this section'><h2>$Text</h2></a><div id=""$div"">"
$fragments+= Get-PingHost -Hostname $Hostname 
$fragments+="</div>"
$fragments+= $html.InnerXml
$fragments+="</div>"


$fragments+= "<p class='footer'>$(get-date)</p>"
```